# YouTube API: How can I get the date/time in which a user marked video as favorite?

Tags: api, youtube, gdata-api, gdata

I'm accessing the feed of a user's favorite videos through the YouTube API. How can I get the date/time in which he marked each video as favorite?

**Update:**

Someone pointed out that the [YouTube API documentation](http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol.html#Favorite_Videos) says that the "Published" date on a user's favorite feed will have the time in which the user marked the video as favorite. But that seems to be false.

For example, check out this video entry:

http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/g2981r_MtHQ

It has a "published" date of `2008-03-19T21:09:09.000Z`.

Now let's see the same video in the favorite feed of some user:

http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/KeepWatchingTheSkies/favorites

It has a "published" date of `2008-03-19T21:09:09.000Z`. Identical.

Here is a different way to get the favorites feed:

http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/base/users/KeepWatchingTheSkies/favorites

And still we have a "published" date of `2008-03-19T21:09:09.000Z`.

Assuming the user was not quick enough to favorite the video on the same millisecond it was published, what's written in the YouTube documentation is probably wrong, and this is *not* the time in which the user marked the video as favorite.

---

So my question is: How can I get the time at which a user marked a video as favorite?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out: The URLs must specify `?v=2` so version 2 of the API will be used.

Here's the fixed URL:

http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/KeepWatchingTheSkies/favorites?v=2

Now it shows a correct "published" time of `2010-09-03T08:59:53.000Z`.

Answer (score 0):

It's easy.

> The <published> tag in a favorite
>   videos feed entry identifies the time
>   that the video was marked as a
>   favorite and not the time that the
>   video was published.

from http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol.html#Favorite_Videos